# How to create delegate function in QT

Tags: c++, delegates

In C# we declare delegate function of a class like this:

```
public delegate void MyClassDelegate(float num);
```

And then we can use it on other functions like this:

```
public int SomeFunction(float num, MyClass.MyClassDelegate del);
```

> How do I do this or something like this on QT?

Comment: In which language? C++? Python?

Comment: @MartinHennings QT C++

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to Qt. Use `std::function` for that:

```
void caller(int value, std::function<float(int)> delegate)
{
    qDebug() << delegate(value);
}

float divide(int value)
{
    return float(value) / 3;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    caller(7, divide);
    return 0;
}
```

If you need something elaborate (such as storing a state to create a proxy function, etc.), you can also use an object with a `()` operator:

```
struct MyDelegate
{
    float operator()(int value) { return float(value) / 3; }
};

float divide(int value)
{
    return float(value) / 3;
}

void caller(int value, MyDelegate& delegate)
{
    qDebug() << delegate(value);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    MyDelegate delegate;
    caller(7, delegate);
    return 0;
}
```